# How to query a WorkItem based on TFS Branch

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm working on a tool to show all code review requests for a specific project's branch.  Right now, the project and corresponding branch lists are populating correctly.  However, when I try to run a query on the WorkItemStore for the TeamProjectCollection, I believe I'm referencing the branch incorrectly.

Here's how I'm loading the branch info, earlier in the code:

```
var projName = ddlProjects.SelectedItem.ToString();

var vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var bos = vcs.QueryRootBranchObjects(RecursionType.Full);
var branchList = bos.Select(branch => branch.Properties.RootItem.Item).ToList();
var finalList = branchList.Where(b => b.Contains(projName)).ToList();
ddlBranches.DataSource = finalList;
```

Here's how I'm running the query that is throwing the error:

```
using (var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(@"http://myTeamProjectCollectionURL")))
{
     var workItemStore = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
     var query = string.Format(@"SELECT *
                                 FROM WorkItems
                                 WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '{0}'
                                 and [System.IterationPath] under '{1}'
                                 and [System.WorkItemType] = 'Code Review Request'", ddlProjects.SelectedItem.ToString(), ddlBranches.SelectedItem.ToString());

     WorkItemCollection workItemCollection = workItemStore.Query(query);
```

And here is the resulting error from the query:

```
TF51011: The specified iteration path does not exist. The error is caused by «'$/ProjectName/ReleaseBranch1.0'».
```

Again, I assume I'm referencing the branch incorrectly in the query.  Does anyone know the correct way to do this?  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Iteration Paths and branches are completely unrelated concepts. Do you explicitly have iteration paths setup to match your branches?

Comment: I figured as much.  No, as far as I know they are not setup that way.  Is there a way to reference the branch in the query, rather than the iteration path?

Answer (score 1):

Work item is created under a team project, not a project. So there is not a field correspond to a Branch by a default.

To achieve what you want, you need to customize a field to specify Branch path, then you have such a query.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Pardon my ignorance though, but would you mind showing me a sample of how to accomplish this?  I am still new to LINQ queries and the TFS API in general.  Thanks again for any additional help you can provide!

Comment: You can add a field with TFS power tools (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1), then you can find the custom field in the query. Refer to this blog: http://amosdk.blogspot.sg/2010/09/how-to-add-custom-field-to-existing.html